# Summation formulas after altering range.

Tags: summation

If i have the following summation to do:  $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{15} (n+1)$$.  I know the formula I would use is $$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ and I would sub in $15$ as $n$ and multiply $1$ by $15$. Now if we change the question to start at $i=0$, for example $$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{15} (n+1)$$  I'm seriously confused as to what to sub in as $n$. According to me, I say 16, but when I've seen other examples $15$ is still subbed in. But for "1" that is multiplied by $16$ as I expected.

Can someone please help me out with a simple explanation to help me understand?

Comment: It's not clear if it is $(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{15} n)+1$ or $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{15} (n+1)$.

Comment: As Element118 said the notation does not clearly state what you mean, please add parenthesis to show what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that
$$\sum_{n=0}^{15}(n+1)=16+\sum_{n=0}^{15}n=16+0+\sum_{n=1}^{15}n.$$
Thus you should sub $n=15$ in your formula.